# Why docker compose links alias not working

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, alias, elk

I have a docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.13.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "cluster.name=elasticsearch" 
      - "discovery.type=single-node" 
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" 
    volumes:
      - /Users/markcwg/mydata/elasticsearch/plugins:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins 
      - /Users/markcwg/mydata/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data 
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.13.3
    container_name: kibana
    links:
      - elasticsearch:es 
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch 
    environment:
      - "elasticsearch.hosts=http://es:9200" 
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
  logstash:
    image: logstash:7.13.3
    container_name: logstash
    volumes:
      - /Users/markcwg/mydata/logstash/logstash-springboot.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf 
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch 
      - kibana
    links:
      - elasticsearch:es 
    ports:
      - 4560:4560
```

Running `docker-compose up -d` created container for all the images files. All containers are running successfully but the problem is that containers cannot interact with each other by alias ('es' in yml file， use 'elasticsearch' is ok)

I'm not able to find answer on https://docs.docker.com/compose/

In short, why link alias is not working?
Or I am going wrong somewhere?

Comment: `links` is a legacy feature and shouldn't be used. As you've noticed you can already reach the service by using `elasticsearch`, and this would be the case even if you remove the link directive. Not sure why the alias is not working though.

Comment: @super - it seems like `links` is back in, when looking at the latest [docker compose spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#links)

Comment: `links:` is still part of the Compose file format (removing it would break compatibility) but there's no reason to use it; Docker networking does all of the things you used to need links for.

Answer (score 0):

Due to memory limitation on play with docker, had to discard logstash
Also had to use Volumes instead of Mount Binding, as it would give access denied for logs in elasticsearch container.

2 container are up and interacting, tested by running dev tool in Kibana.

Here is how the docker-compose.yml looked at the end

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.13.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "cluster.name=elasticsearch" 
      - "discovery.type=single-node" 
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" 
    volumes:
      - myplugins:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins 
      - myesdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - myeslogs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.13.3
    container_name: kibana
    links:
      - elasticsearch:es 
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch 
    environment:
      - "elasticsearch.hosts=http://es:9200" 
    ports:
      - 5601:5601

volumes:
  myplugins:
  myesdata:
  myeslogs:
```

[image: Here is the output of kibana]

Observations:

1. Have tried the same configuration by removing `links` and replacing `es` with `localhost` to look like below and it worked as well.

```
 environment:
    - "elasticsearch.hosts=http://localhost:9200"
```

Reason for that is When `network` is not mentioned, all the containers built using composer are binded by a default network based on parent folder such that containers could interact.

2. Mount Binding is causing Elasticsearch container to exit hence causing Kibana to not start. Hence used volume.
3. The 2nd port binding `9300:9300` is not needed for elasticsearch service.